# Akka and Supervisor Strategies that fallback

Tags: akka, akka-supervision

I am brand new to Akka but my *understanding* about the `Stop` directive is that it is used inside of `SupervisorStrategies` when the child should be considered permanently out of service, but there is a way to handle the total outage.

If that understanding is correct, then what I would like to do is have some kind of a “backup actor” that should be engaged after the normal/primary child is stopped and used from that point forward as a fallback. For example, say I have a parent actor who has a child actor - `Notifier` - whose job it is to send emails. If the `Notifier` truly dies (say, the underlying mail server goes offline), a backup to this actor might be another actor, say, `QueueClient`, that sends the notification request to a message broker, where the message will be queued up and replayed at a later time.

How can I define such a `SupervisorStrategy` to have this built in fault tolerance/actor backup inside of it? Please show code examples, its the only way I will learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding Supervisor Strategies beyond the default directives is not commonly done, and not really necessary in your case. A solution would be to watch the child actor from the parent, and when the parent finds that the child is stopped, engage the backup actor.

import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Stop
    import akka.actor._

```
class Parent extends Actor {

  var child: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[DefaultChild])
  context.watch(child)

  def receive = {
    case Terminated(actor) if actor == child => 
      child = context.actorOf(Props[BackupChild])
  }

  override def supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case ex: IllegalStateException => Stop
  }
}

class DefaultChild extends Actor {

  def receive = { case _ => throw new IllegalStateException("whatever") }
}

class BackupChild extends Actor {

  def receive = { case _ => }
}
```